# How do I do multiline foreign imports with ghcjs?

Tags: haskell, ghcjs

How do I do multiline foreign imports in GHCJS? I have a block of javascript that stretches over multiple lines:

```
foreign import javascript unsafe
  "{ var x = 41;\
  \  $r = x + 1; \
  \}"
  answerToGreatestQuestion :: IO (JSRef Double)
```

And I get an error like:

```
lexical error in string/character literal at character 'i'
```

which points to the `\` character. What's going on here?

Answer (score 5):

If you're within a CPP block, remove the leading `\` from each line. See [this issue](https://github.com/ghcjs/ghcjs/issues/84).